# Grafana: how to automate user/team creation in Helm chart installation

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, helm3

I am using Grafana Helm chart to install Grafana on K8s cluster.
The procedure works quite good, also predefining dashboards, so that they are accessible after installation.On the other hand I didn’t find a solution to automate the creation of users & teams so far.
How can I specify/predefine users + teams , so that they are being created on “helm install”-ing the chart ?

Any hint highly appreciated

PS: I am aware of the HTTP API , but I am more interested in a way to predefine the info and having "helm install..." is setting up the whole stack

Comment: What have you tried before posting the question? I can only think of some job which will be executed after grafana is installed and running and add everything via API calls. From my understanding grafana should be running before you add any users. (well, I'm not an expert in grafana)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I didn't try anything in particular, but I am looking for a method to specify users/teams upfront....the same way as I can define dashboards, datasources, etc upfront and then they got setup via ```helm install ....``` command.
If this is not possible, yes, then I have to go the script way after Grafana has been setup.

Answer (score 1):

there isn't `helm install` available for creating user(s)/group(s) for grafana. the best way is through HTTP API, However, Ansible playbook might be an option too